# Jackson: Check if ArrayNode contains JsonNode

Tags: java, jackson, objectmapper, jsonnode

I am using the [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) JSON library and its *Tree Model* system (`JsonNode`) in my Java application. In this, I need to check if an `ArrayNode` contains a given `JsonNode`. I was looking through the JavaDocs and I did not see any sort of `.contains()` method for `ArrayNode`. I ended up writing a contains methods myself:

```
   public static boolean arrayNodeContains(ArrayNode arrayNode, JsonNode node) {
      Stream<JsonNode> nodeStream = StreamSupport.stream(arrayNode.spliterator(), false);
      return nodeStream.anyMatch(j -> j.equals(node));
   }
```

Unit Test:

```
   @Test
   public void testArrayNodeContains()
         throws IOException
   {
      ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper;

      String arrayJsonString = "[{\"foo\":\"bar\"},{\"foo\":\"baz\"},{\"baz\":\"bar\"}]";
      String nodeTrueJsonString = "{\"foo\":\"bar\"}";
      String nodeFalseJsonString = "{\"foo\":\"brains\"}";
      List<Object> list = mapper.readValue(arrayJsonString, List.class);
      ArrayNode arrayNode = mapper.valueToTree(list);

      Map<String, Object> nodeTrueMap = mapper.readValue(nodeTrueJsonString, Map.class);
      JsonNode nodeTrue = mapper.valueToTree(nodeTrueMap);

      assertTrue(arrayNodeContains(arrayNode, nodeTrue));

      Map<String, Object> nodeFalseMap = mapper.readValue(nodeFalseJsonString, Map.class);
      JsonNode nodeFalse = mapper.valueToTree(nodeFalseMap);
      assertFalse(arrayNodeContains(arrayNode, nodeFalse));
   }
```

Did I miss something in Jackson and I am duplicating some library method I missed. Otherwise, is there a better way of doing this than what I did?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an option of using [equals](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/node/ArrayNode.html#equals-java.util.Comparator-com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode-) method with JsonNode and Comparator

> Entry method for invoking customizable comparison, using passed-in Comparator object. Nodes will handle traversal of structured types (arrays, objects), but defer to comparator for scalar value comparisons

New Enhancement 790 for adding [JsonNode.equals(Comparator, JsonNode)](https://github.com/fasterxml/jackson-databind/issues/790) to support configurable/external equality comparison:

> ```
>  // but. Custom comparator can make all the difference
>     Comparator<JsonNode> cmp = new Comparator<JsonNode>() {
>         @Override
>         public int compare(JsonNode o1, JsonNode o2) {
>             if (o1.equals(o2)) {
>                 return 0;
>             }
>             if ((o1 instanceof NumericNode) && (o2 instanceof NumericNode)) {
>                 double d1 = ((NumericNode) o1).asDouble();
>                 double d2 = ((NumericNode) o2).asDouble();
>                 if (d1 == d2) { // strictly equals because it's integral value
>                     return 1;
>                 }
>             }
>             return 0;
>         }
>     };
>     // but with custom comparator, yes
>     assertTrue(root1.equals(cmp, root2));
> ```